# Comment exprimer son enthousiasme dans un niveau de langage soutenu ?

Tags: formulation, registre-soutenu

Je suis confronté à une situation où je voudrais exprimer ma gratitude d'une manière qui paraisse enthousiaste, mais sans tomber dans le langage familier (il s'agit d'une conversation par mail d'ordre professionnelle) : je voudrais donc éviter les :

> Super, merci beaucoup !

et autres (vieillot) :

> Formidable !

mais sans non plus tomber dans un registre trop formel et dénué de chaleur :

> Je vous remercie de votre action qui me sera fort bénéfique.

(Après tout, nous ne sommes pas des robots !)

Quelle formulation pourrait être adéquate ?

Comment: Quel est le contexte (Pourquoi la remercies-tu?) et à quel profil de personne t'adresses-tu? (Jeune, âgé, inconnu) (Si ce n'est indiscret)

Comment: Donc tu veux éviter le registre genre "Je vous en sais/saurais bon grès" ?

Answer (score 1):

Tout dépend du contexte évidemment.  Pourquoi pas :

> Merci beaucoup !  Je suis très sensible à ce que vous avez fait pour moi.

Answer (score 1):

L'enthousiasme va souvent de pair avec l'impatience, s'il s'agit par exemple d'une promotion tu peux faire part de ton envie de commencer rapidement.
Dans le cas où un supérieur hiérarchique t'aurait recommandé pour un nouveau poste tu pourrais dire:

> J'ai vraiment hâte de débuter cette nouvelle activité

et ajouter

> Je vous suis profondément reconnaissant.

par exemple.

La question n'étant pas assez précise je ne peux pas donner d'exemple qui colleraient bien à ton cas.

Answer (score 1):

Je dois souligner que d'après les exemple informels choisis il s'agit beaucoup de reconnaissance et non d'enthousiasme et je considère donc la question dans ce premier sens.

Voici trois possibilités qui sont assez formelles et qui peuvent, comme c'est souvent le cas, être utilisées pour écrire de nombreuses variantes pourvu que l'on s'en tienne à des remplacement ou des ajouts dans un vocabulaire similairement formel.

- Je tiens à vous faire part de toute la gratitude qui est la mienne à votre égard  suite à la  décision que vous avez prise de me faire le favori.
- Je ne sais comment vous témoigner l'inexprimable reconnaissance que j'ai envers vous pour m'avoir choisi.
- Votre choix de ma personne pour le poste restera à jamais dans mon esprit associé à une ineffable reconnaissance à votre endroit.

Comment: *Inexpressible* ? Autant éviter l'anglais, qui plus est en français soutenu, donc : *inexprimable*.

Comment: @jlliagre Merci.(TLFi) : Rem. Chez Loti, adj. synon. de inexprimable. D'autres sentiments inexpressibles m'arrivaient aussi, sortis toujours des mêmes insondables dessous, et complétant un bien étrange ensemble (Rom. enf., 1890, p. 229). Cependant, la mot vient bien de l'anglais chez moi.